# Xcode server - TestSummaries.plist

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, automated-tests, xcode9, xcode-server

we are trying to get TestSummaries.plist.
Previously, it was inside xcodebuild_result.bundle.zip as describe in the [blog](https://honzadvorsky.com/articles/2015-05-04-under-the-hood-of-xcode-server/)

Now in **Xcode 9**, I couldn't find it.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The "xcodebuild_result.bundle.zip" still appears to have a Test Summaries plist. In a recent integration, I found a "TestSummaries.plist" at the root of the archive, as well as a "action_TestSummaries.plist" in each of the tested devices folders.

[image]